# Haskell I can not get exception ReadFile with try

Tags: haskell, try-catch, option-type, either

I have a function "management" that checks parameters and return a Maybe (String):

- If there are not parameter -> return Nothing
- If my parameter is equal to "-h" -> Return a string help

My problem arrived when I get a file and check if this file exists.

> Couldn't match expected type ‘Maybe String’
>                     with actual type ‘IO (Either e0 a2)’

```
managagment :: [String] -> Maybe (String)
managagment [] = Nothing
managagment ["-h"] = Just (help)
managagment [file] = try $ readFile file >>= \result -> case result of
                                                        Left e -> Nothing
                                                        Right content -> Just (content)
```

Comment: What do you think the type of `readFile` is?

Comment: Similarly, what do you think the type of `try` is? what does ghci say when you check?

Comment: Ghci return "IO (Either e a)", Either is composed of two constuctors Left and Right. That's what I do

Comment: `Just "help"`, not `Just help`.

Comment: help is a function that return a String (help :: String)

Comment: If it doesn't have input, `help` is not a function.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are several problems

**Function application (`$`) is lower precedence than bind (`>>=`)**

You said:

```
try $ readFile file >>= \res...
```

Which means

```
try ( readFile file >>= \res... )
```

But you wanted:

```
try ( readFile file ) >>= \res...
```

**`IO (Maybe a)` and `Maybe a` are distinct**

You have a function using IO (via `readFile` and `try`) but many of the cases do not return an IO result (`Nothing` and `Just content`).

Solution: Return via `return Nothing` or `pure Nothing` to lift a value into the IO monad.

**The exception type was ambiguous**

The `try` function can catch any exception type, just look at the signature:

```
try :: Exception e => IO a -> IO (Either e a)
```

When you totally ignore the exception you leave the type checker with no information to decide what `e` should be.  In these situations an explicit type signature is useful, such as:

```
  Left (e::SomeException) -> pure Nothing
```

**`managagment` is partial**

`managagment ["a","b"]` is undefined as is any input list of length over one.  Consider a final equational definition of:

```
managagment _ = managagment ["-h"]
```

Or more directly:

```
managagment _ = pure $ Just help
```

**Style and other notes**

- `managagment` should probably `management`
- `Just (foo)` is generally `Just foo`
- `help` is not a function that returns a String.  It is a value of type String.
- The example was not complete, missing imports and `help`.

**Fixed Code**

Consider instead:

```
#!/usr/bin/env cabal
{- cabal:
    build-depends: base
-}
{-# LANGUAGE ScopedTypeVariables #-}
{-# LANGUAGE LambdaCase          #-}
import Control.Exception (try, SomeException)

main :: IO ()
main = print =<< management []

help :: String
help = "so helpful"

management :: [String] -> IO (Maybe String)
management [] = pure Nothing
management ["-h"] = pure $ Just help
management [file] =
    try (readFile file) >>=
      \case
         Left (e::SomeException) -> pure Nothing
         Right content -> pure $ Just content
management _ = pure $ Just help
```

And test as such:

```
% chmod +x x.hs
% ./x.hs
```